# MKRoadWidthAtZoomScale in iOS 6?

Tags: ios, mapkit

From the docs for `MKRoadWidthAtZoomScale`:

> You should not use this function to retrieve road widths in iOS 6 and later.

Is there another function that could be used instead, or is this just missing functionality in iOS 6?

It's odd that the function wasn't deprecated, if you shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd hazard a guess that it wasn't deprecated because the functionality will be added back in at some point. The function still works in iOS 6, as in it doesn't cause a crash when called, even though the output isn't useful.

If you look at the (Apple) Maps app, you can see that when you zoom into a directions path, the width of the path increases at the highest zoom levels. The width of the road increases at those high zoom levels too. Obviously Apple has an internal way to know how wide the roads get when zooming. Maybe it hasn't been fully tested for general release.

Just in case anyone thinks you can still use this function, here's the suggested road widths starting at fully zoomed in (MKZoomScale = 1) and zooming out.

Code:

```
for (float zoomScale=1; zoomScale>0.00001; zoomScale /= 2) {
    NSLog(@"zoomScale: %f Road Width: %f", zoomScale, MKRoadWidthAtZoomScale(zoomScale));
}
```

Results:

```
zoomScale: 1.000000 Road Width: 21.000000
zoomScale: 0.500000 Road Width: 32.000000
zoomScale: 0.250000 Road Width: 60.000000
zoomScale: 0.125000 Road Width: 96.000000
zoomScale: 0.062500 Road Width: 176.000000
zoomScale: 0.031250 Road Width: 288.000000
zoomScale: 0.015625 Road Width: 448.000000
zoomScale: 0.007812 Road Width: 768.000000
zoomScale: 0.003906 Road Width: 1536.000000
zoomScale: 0.001953 Road Width: 2048.000000
...
```

As for a replacement function, I'd suggest just creating some values that work well for the highest 2 or 3 zoom levels and using a constant value below that.

Here's the Apple maps route overlay at low and high zooms. You can see that the alternative route isn't taking the larger road width into consideration, but the main route width is spot on. Changing the route doesn't affect the alternative route width.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the trouble to write this. Unfortunately I find it quite hard to follow. Using the forbidden function *does* give you a fairly reasonable result (I've tries it). Using a constant at zoomed-out levels would give very thin lines. Apples's choice to show lines at two different widths perhaps indicates why they think one function isn't the way to go, but doesn't seem to say anything about `MkRoadMapWidthAtZoomScale` itself.

Comment: When you say you got reasonable results, how were you using `MKRoadWidthAtZoomScale()` and what OS was it working on? When I say "using a constant" I mean use a constant for the road width in points instead of getting the road width from a function. This will give you _fat_ lines when zoomed out, not thin ones. Zoomed in, if you don't change the width, the lines will be too thin.

Comment: How was I using it: basically CGContextSetLineWidth(context, MKRoadWidthAtZoomScale(zoomScale)); on iOS 6.1.  I just tried a constant - 5000 - and I can only think you are using 'zoomed in' the opposite way I think of it - for me, map features are really big when zoomed in, and the line is fat, and I see entire countries when zoomed out, and the line is thin.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 7.1 there is no warning in the documentation about  `MKRoadWidthAtZoomScale` anymore. It is defined in `MKOverlayRenderer.h`, which was introduced in iOS 7.0.